# Wired mouse detected but not responding

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, mouse

I have a wired mouse connected to my Macbook Pro, OS X 10.9.5.  The mouse is powered, but completely unresponsive.  The mouse works on my windows machine, and the usb port on my Macbook works with other mouses/devices.  The mouse is detected in my System Information as

```
  USB OPTICAL MOUSE:
  Product ID:   0x0a4c
  Vendor ID:    0x15d9
  Version:   1.00
  Speed:    Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
  Location ID:  0x14100000 / 8
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
```

I have tried resetting my PRAM, with no effect.

Does anyone know what steps I can take to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one to have problems with this [particular brand of mouse](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5233168).

Comment: I have a very similar mouse i guess. My problem is it gets disconnected randomly.

```    USB OPTICAL MOUSE :

          Product ID: 0x0f97
          Vendor ID: 0x18f8
          Version: 1.00
          Speed: Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
          Location ID: 0x14100000 / 26
          Current Available (mA): 1000
          Current Required (mA): 100
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0```

So it looks like we got to buy a new mouse :(

Answer (score -1):

I think your Mac book not providing proper current and voltages. A normal wired mouse requires 5 volts of voltages and 0.9 ampere of current to work properly

Comment: 1 ampere for a mouse? Must be a heavy duty mouse then :-) USB 2.0 allows up to 500 mA, USB 3.0 up to 900 mA.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake... :-)